# Is standard C <signal.h> buggy on Visual 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, signals

I've recently added a new functionality to a CLI, based on trapping "Ctrl+C" signal.
To my delight, I discovered that [`<signal.h>` is part of standard C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/signal_h.htm), and should therefore be available on any C standard compliant environment.

The first operation when entering an interrupt is to disable said interrupt, to avoid stacking multiple identical interruptions.
This is done easily through following line : 
[`signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/SIG_strategies).

Unfortunately, for Visual Studio 2008, it generates the following warning :

> warning C4306: 'type cast' : conversion from 'int' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' of greater size

While it doesn't clearly name the impacted argument, it seems to be targeting `SIG_IGN`, which should be of type `void (__cdecl *)(int)`.

`SIG_IGN` is provided by `<signal.h>`, so it should be usable directly, without any cast issue.

Questions are :

- Is Visual 2008 implementation of `<signal.h>` buggy ?
- Are other versions of Visual affected ?
- How to fix that issue ? explicit casting ?

(Note : I don't have Visual Studio locally, so I have to "guess" the behaviour before shipping. I'm receiving test reports run remotely, but it takes some time get here.)

Comment: I don't remember VS2008 having this problem, but it is already 3 doglives ago.  Signals are a strong Unix implementation detail and have no good mapping to Windows SEH exceptions.  Best to read the MSDN article for signal(), quote: "SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application." The SetConsoleCtrlHandler() winapi function is a substitute of sorts.  It lets you write a callback function that runs when Ctrl+C is typed or the console Close button is clicked, it is however not possible to ignore it.